Symfony - NumberFormatter - Format numbers with either two fraction digits or no fraction digit
I render a monetary value in Twig like this:
{{ amount | format_currency('EUR', {fraction_digit: 2, decimal_always_shown: false}, 'fr-FR') }}

If amount has no decimal, I want to render it without fraction digit (ex: 12);
if it has some decimals, I want to render it with 2 fraction digits exactly (ex: 12.10 and 12.23).
Trying some parameters combinations (like the one above), the value 12.10 is rendered 12.1 while I would like to render 12.10.
Is there any way to do so using params from here https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/filters/format_currency.html. Params seem to be the same as NumberFormatter (https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.numberformatter.php#numberformatter.constants.lenient-parse).

Unsure why you would want to display currencies in two different ways? Anyway consider creating a custom filter/function which detects if the variable has decimals or not before applying the NumberFormatter

You have to test the value first to see if it has a fractional value, and conditionally format with appropriate parameters.
{% if amount|round(2, 'common') == amount|round(0, 'floor') %}
  {{ amount | format_currency('EUR', {fraction_digit: 0}, 'fr-FR') }}
{% else %}
  {{ amount | format_currency('EUR', {fraction_digit: 2}, 'fr-FR') }}
{% endif %}

Or conditionally set the parameter value before formatting.
{% set deci = (amount|round(2, 'common') == amount|round(0, 'floor')) ? 0 : 2 %}
{{ amount | format_currency('EUR', {fraction_digit: deci}, 'fr-FR') }}

Or you can just inline the ternary:
{{ amount | format_currency('EUR', {fraction_digit: (amount|round(2, 'common') == amount|round(0, 'floor')) ? 0 : 2}, 'fr-FR') }}

Tested here with number_format

Why don't you put this logic in a custom twig filter (or function)?
